# Using CSS only: change a div's background color on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is a link to another page. When someone hovers over the div(ie, link) I want the whole div's background color to go blue. I would like to do this all in CSS because javascript may not work with everyone.

**My Problem:** My code below attempts to do this, the link works fine BUT when I hover over the div the background doesn't change color. What do you think I am doing wrong & how do you think I can fix this to make the div change background color on hover?

I have a feeling that I should place the link(a element) inside the div(instead of outside) but I can never get the a to stretch to the full space of the div that way.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body        { background-color: RGB(218,238,248); }
        #rentalAnnc { margin-top: 5%; border-color: #99CCFF; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
                      border-width:thin; border-style:solid; border-right-width:thick;
                      border-bottom-width:thick; background-color: #FFFFFF; width: 300px; }

        /* Using pure CSS I am trying to make the background color of the div renatalAnnc have a blue background when we hover over it*/
        .sidebarLink { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
        .sidebarLink a:hover { background-color: blue; }

        /* The following on works in Firefox not IE! :( #rentalAnnc:hover { background-color: blue; } */
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a class="sidebarLink" href="facilitiesForHire.html">
        <div id="rentalAnnc">
            <p>We have a range of Education Facilities available for lease & hire</p>
        </div>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A `<div>` in `<a>` is not valid HTML. So browser behaviour is in any way undetermined/unstandard. http://validator.w3.org.

Comment: @BalusC: HTML5 allows `<div>` within `<a>`.

Comment: @mu is: Is that so? I'm behind on the times.

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, check the validator that BalusC linked to (just be sure to specify HTML5 in the options). Of course assuming that browsers  understand HTML5 is a risky proposition.

Comment: @muis: OP did not show a HTML5 document. It's a doctypeless document.

Comment: is it ok to have a ul, ol or p inside a <a> element? Refering to HTML4 & less

Comment: Should also specify IE version, as always.

Comment: @BalusC: And you didn't qualify your validity statement. But there's no need for this to get petty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `<a>` inside the `<div>`. If you want it to stretch across the full space, add `display: block` to its style.

```
<div id="rentalAnnc">
    <a class="sidebarLink" href="facilitiesForHire.html">
        <p>We have a range of Education Facilities available for lease and hire</p>
    </a>
</div>

a.sidebarLink { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; display: block; }
a.sidebarLink:hover { background-color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`:hover` support is not great for non-anchor elements in older browsers and IE, so you can attach the hover psuedo class to the `<a>` instead and use a simple descendant selector:

```
a:hover #rentalAnnc { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: Well this actually may not suffice, it will trigger on `a:hover`, not specifically on `#rentalAnnc:hover`. So, if your `<a>` element is larger than your `#rentalAnnc`, you won't get the "staggered" hover effect as the mouse moves into the element, but it does at least work around IE6 and 7's sub-par :hover support.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to top of your page to make it a HTML5 document and use the outcommented `#rentalAnnc:hover { background-color: blue; }` rule. Having a `<div>` inside `<a>` is invalid in HTML3/4, but apparently valid in HTML5 (disclaimer: HTML5 standard is still not definitive). After adding the proper doctype and the outcommented rule, your current problem (and many other (future?) layout-related issues) should be solved in MSIE.

Don't forget to fix the other http://validator.w3.org errors after adding the doctype, such as a missing title and so on. Browser behaviour is undetermined on invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I'm sure but I've been looking at this recently and I think the better solution is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body        { background-color: RGB(218,238,248); }
    #rentalAnnc { margin-top: 5%; border-color: #99CCFF; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
                  border-width:thin; border-style:solid; border-right-width:thick;
                  border-bottom-width:thick; width: 300px; }
    a.sidebarLink div { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; background-color: #FFFFFF;}
    a.sidebarLink:hover div { background-color: blue; }
</style>

<a class="sidebarLink" href="facilitiesForHire.html">
    <div id="rentalAnnc">
        <p>We have a range of Education Facilities available for lease & hire</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Note: the rentalAnnc div does not have a background-color in it's style. This is in the link style only.

This way, the link covers the entire div exactly, not just a part of it. Also, any background-image applied to the div (eg with transparent areas for the background color to show through) will still be displayed!